# Making linked select options using handlebars

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, handlebars.js

Is there a way in handlebars JS to link two different select option in a way that if a select option (1) from the first select, i see options (1,2) in the second, or if i select option (2) in the first, i see options (3,4) in the second.
Something like this:

```
<select class="form-control" id="firstSelect">
                {{#select firstSelect}}
                <option value="a" selected> a</option>
                <option value="b"> b </option> </option> 
                {{/select}}   
</select>        
<select class="form-control" id="secondSelect">
                {{#if firstSelect == 'a'}}
                <option value="1" selected> 1</option>
                <option value="2"> b </option>2</option> 
                {{/if}}
                 {{#if firstSelect == 'b'}}
                <option value="3" selected> 3</option>
                <option value="4"> b </option>4</option> 
                {{/if}}
</select>
```